# Program that calculates moduo/ratio/gear radius

Tags: python, list, math, range

So, a little bit of the background, before I explain the program needs.

Currently I am working as a mechanical engineer in a company that specilizes in gerbox/gearset design and optimatization.

Currently I am working on a project that requires two stage gearbox (all gears are helical), so no planetary gears etc.
In our previous calculations and everyday job, we were using software called KissSoft. Stuff that KissSoft does is, calculation of gear micro/macro geometry and finesizing.
For this task I do not need that, because of all limitations and required inputs needed

Program that I want to make is something that will give me every single combination of gear radius in regard to number of teeth/moduo and vice versa. There is also a requirement to satistfy the gear ratio of 10.
Also, axial distance that needs to be satisfied is 295 between input gear axis and output gear axis. Two stage - three axis. From previous experience, soemthing like this is not possible, due to the big axial distance - for a gear ratio of 10 it should be between 240-26. But the customer doesnt want to hear about it.

Gear ratio between first and second gear should vary between 2.22-3 and between third and fourth should vary between 3.33-4.5. So that multiplication of two can give ratio of 10.

Ratio is needed for determination of number of teeth: i1-2 = z2/z1 etc.

Gear radius: d1=m * z1. Note: first gear, one that is driving, should have minimal number of teeth 20.

Moduo is a relation between gear radius and number of teeth - d/z.

Moduo should also vary in range of 2.5 to 3.

My question is, since I am pretty much new in computing and programming, how can I set a program like this?
Probably, I will need a list of moduo and ratio in a given range? I could easily set up the math equations needed, but how can I make the program give me every possible combination?
To give me the output of: i12, i34, d1, d2 etc.

If the question is ill formated, will reformat :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example